# Cannot send data to my DB

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to insert my `dropdownlist` and my `textbox` values to my database stored procedure but it doesn't insert and also doesn't give me any error. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
protected void btnPlaceScores_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string conn = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconn"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection myconnection = new SqlConnection(conn))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("MatchScores", myconnection);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("HomeTeam", drop1.SelectedItem.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("AwayTeam", drop2.SelectedItem.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Scores", txtScores.Text);

        try
        {
            myconnection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch {  }
        finally
        {
            myconnection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: An empty catch block won't help you to find an error (BTW you don't need to manually close connection, using statement will do it for you).

Comment: Remove your `try catch finally` as the `using` already deals with what you're doing.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Catch should look like this:  `catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: '{0}'", e); }`

Comment: I've done you told me (thank you by the way) but it still doesn't insert those values and still doesn't give me any error.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're using Microsoft SQL, normally parameters start with an '@'

```
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HomeTeam", drop1.SelectedItem.Value);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AwayTeam", drop2.SelectedItem.Value);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Scores", txtScores.Text);
```

Comment: I first tried using the @ but that didn't work either

Comment: @GabrielTakyie do you happen to have the stored procedure?